# Groovy:How to replace Body tag for existing xml file in soapui

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui

I am trying to replace Body of XML coming from mock request to an existing XML schema. Could you please anyone help me to achieve this

Body of XML (Which has taken from txt file) that needs to be replaced into Base XML file:

```
<tns:Body xmlns:tns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <polsearch1:searchForPoliciesResponse xmlns:polsearch1="http://service.axa.de/komposit/policyretrieve/searchforpoliciesmodel/v1">
         <polsearch1:Entry Address="Colonia-Allee" AddressLine1="Colonia-Allee" City="Köln" EffectiveDate="2020-02-06T00:00:00+01:00" ExpirationDate="2021-02-06T00:00:00+01:00" InsuredName="Herr Dr. Axafiname Ovuir Suf" IsArchived="false" PolicyNumber="56000068476" PolicyType="VHV19Household" PostalCode="51067" ProducerCode="8834002000" Status="inforce" HouseNumber_De="10" DateOfBirth_De="1990-08-26T00:00:00+02:00"/>
      </polsearch1:searchForPoliciesResponse>
   </tns:Body>
```

My base XML file:

```
<tns:Envelope xmlns:tns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <tns:Header>
      some info;
   </tns:Header>
   <tns:Body>
      <polsearch1:searchForPoliciesResponse xmlns:polsearch1="http://service.axa.de/komposit/policyretrieve/searchforpoliciesmodel/v1">
         <polsearch1:Entry Address="Colonia-Allee" AddressLine1="Colonia-Allee" City="Köln" EffectiveDate="2019-02-27T00:01:00+01:00" ExpirationDate="2020-02-27T00:01:00+01:00" InsuredName="Mr. Testklasklsk Testqerqwerwqe" IsArchived="false" PolicyNumber="${#MockResponse#Request#declare namespace v1='http://service.axa.de/komposit/policyretrieve/searchforpoliciesmodel/v1'; //v1:searchForPolicies[1]/v1:criteria[1]/@PolicyNumber}" PolicyType="HR19LiabilityRetail" PostalCode="51067" ProducerCode="8834002000" Status="inforce" HouseNumber_De="88" DateOfBirth_De="1987-12-12T00:00:00+01:00"/>
      </polsearch1:searchForPoliciesResponse>
   </tns:Body>
</tns:Envelope>
```

And my Groovy script is like:

```
jsonObjectForPartner = jsonSlurper.parseText(line) //line contains Body of xml from txt file 


String tempContent = new File(groovyUtils.projectPath+"/sp_baseFile.xml").getText('UTF-8') // reading Base file xml
    def Basefileholder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(tempContent) //taking into XMLholder class

//replacing the body content
Basefileholder.setNodeValue("//*:Body",jsonObjectForPolicy.line)
```

using setNodevalue I could able to place string but existing content is not removing. Can anyone help on this?

Comment: I'm confused why you're reading your body XML with a jsonSlurper.  Wouldn't you want to parse it into an XML node as well?  If you have an XML node, you can probably use `.replaceNode(foo)` to replace the current Body with the new node.

Comment: That's not a body of xml. I have taken it from txt file and to get required attribute I used JsonSluper. Anyhow I got solution for this question. I have removed Body tag from existing xml and replaced with this string (which contains body of xml). However, I will try with your solution too. Thank you so much for your reply.

And Worked code:
Basefileholder.removeDomNodes("//*:Body/*:searchForPoliciesResponse") 
  Basefileholder.setNodeValue("//*:Body",jsonObjectForPolicy.XMLBodyResponse)
  finalxml = Basefileholder.xml.replace("&lt;", "<")
  mockResponse.responseContent = finalxml

Comment: you can post your solution as well in that case

Comment: Added solution for my question, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for this question is:

SearchPolicies.txt - contains actual output (Body of xml in string format)

Sp_base.xml - contains sample schema

Task: replacing xml body content from Txt file to base xml file

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
//Get Mockrequest
def requestholder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(mockRequest.requestContent)
//log.info(requestholder)
//get project root folder path
def projRootLocation = groovyUtils.projectPath
//log.info(projRootLocation)
//parent folder path
def requestSampleFileFolder = projRootLocation  
//Get the info of the Policy to be searched from request
def policynumber = requestholder.getNodeValue("//*:Body/*:searchForPolicies/*:criteria/@PolicyNumber")
//log.info(policynumber)

 //Check for the POLICY whethere existed in already created data
def allRowsDataForCreatedPolicies = new File(requestSampleFileFolder + "/SearchPolicies.txt").readLines()
def jsonObjectForPolicy 
def policyFound = false
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
allRowsDataForCreatedPolicies.find { String line ->  
  if(line.contains(policynumber))
  {
  log.info(line)      
  policyFound = true  
  jsonObjectForPolicy = jsonSlurper.parseText(line)
  true
  }
}
//Get base file
String tempContent = new File(groovyUtils.projectPath+"/sp_baseFile.xml").getText('UTF-8')
def Basefileholder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(tempContent)
def finalResponse
if(policyFound)
{
    //Removing the searchForPoliciesResponse node to replace with actual output 
      Basefileholder.removeDomNodes("//*:Body/*:searchForPoliciesResponse") 
      //Replacing the required body content to the base schema file
    Basefileholder.setNodeValue("//*:Body",jsonObjectForPolicy.XMLBodyResponse)
    //Removing unwanted charecters from xml
    finalResponse = Basefileholder.xml.replace("&lt;", "<")
    //Dsipatching the final response
    mockResponse.responseContent = finalResponse
}
else {mockResponse.responseContent = "Policy Number not found"}
```